# Поворот персонажа в сторону движения 3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть 3D игра с видом сверху. В игре нужно бегать за человечка используя виртуальный джойстик и мне нужно чтобы игрок поворачивался в сторону движения, я не пойму как это можно сделать.
[Видео](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/NjEpeL9FdUZoxQ)

На видео я управляю игроком, у него есть носик на голове и игрок носиком должен смотреть в ту сторону в которую Направлен джойстик. Но я не знаю как это реализовать.
Вот так у меня игрок двигается

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
   public Joystick joystick;
   public Rigidbody rb;
   public Vector3 vector3;
   public ParticleSystem particleSys; 
   public float _speed;
   
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); 
    }


    void Update()
    {
        vector3.x = joystick.Horizontal;
        vector3.z = joystick.Vertical;
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(vector3.x * _speed, transform.position.y, vector3.z * _speed);   
    } 
}
```

Comment: Надеюсь я сделал правильно

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо добавить поворот персонажу. Можно реализовать с помощью AddTorque. В качестве инпута также используете джойстик
https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2019.4/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html